# MySQL for Visual Studio exception

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, exception, logging

I'm trying to link a MySQL Database to my C# project, but I've run into a few snags. In Visual Studio, when I try to connect to a database, it prompts me to update the configuration for MySQL for Visual Studio. If I click "yes" and run the update tool, I get this exception:

```
MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.LoggerUndefinedLogFileException: The Logger properties that define a log file path and name have not been set.
   in MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.Logger..ctor()
   in MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.Logger.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0()
   in System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from the previous location where the exception was thrown ---
   in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   in System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   in MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.Logger.get_Instance()
   in MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.Logger.LogEvent(TraceEventType type, Int32 id, String message, Boolean displayOnUserInterface)
   in MySql.Utility.Classes.Logging.Logger.LogError(String message, Boolean displayOnUserInterface)
   in MySql.VisualStudio.CustomAction.CustomActions.GetPkgdefFileStatus(SupportedVisualStudioVersions visualStudioVersion, Version mysqlForVisualStudioVersion)
   in MySql.VisualStudio.CustomAction.CustomActions.GetPkgdefFileStatuses(Version mysqlForVisualStudioVersion)
   in MySql.VisualStudio.CustomAction.CustomActions.IsConfigurationUpdateRequired(Version mysqlForVisualStudioVersion, Version installedMySqlDataVersion, Version internalMySqlDataVersion)
   in MySql.VisualStudio.Updater.UpdaterMainForm.UpdatePkgDefFiles()
   in MySql.VisualStudio.Updater.UpdaterMainForm.<Initialize>b__7_0()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from the previous location where the exception was thrown ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   in MySql.VisualStudio.Updater.UpdaterMainForm.<Initialize>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from the previous location where the exception was thrown ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
```

If I don't, when I try to pick a database from the database list, I get the error "Unable to retrieve the list of databases".

I've tried reinstalling the MySQL extensions for Visual Studio (via NuGet) and the MySQL packages (via MySQL installer - community) but the errors persist. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to MySQL database server? Can you share the code which throws the exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm trying to connect via Visual Studio 2017, through Server Explorer -> Connect to Database, then I pick MySQL Database as the data source. As for the exception, it pops up when I try to run the "MySQL for Visual Studio Configuration Update Tool", which I'm prompted to run when I click the "Connect to Database" button.

If I opt not to run the tool, after I choose the data source, input the server name, user name and password and try to pick a database name, I get the error "Unable to retrieve the list of databases".

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Adding another reply because I reached the character limit. I don't know where in the code the exception comes from apart from the stack trace I posted.